# How To Read Stream From IdHTTP.Get

Tags: delphi, indy

```
HTTP.Request.Connection:= 'Keep-Alive';
HTTP.Request.CacheControl:= 'no-cache';
HTTP.Request.ContentType:= 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';    
HTTP.Get('jpip://192.168.1.71:3312/cb.jp2?len=4000&type=jpp-stream&cnew=http&tid=0 HTTP/1.1', response);
```

I want to read response (i defined as a TStream). But i don' t know to idHttp.Get usage?

How can i get the response from server (byte byte).

Comment: How are we supposed to know your server installed somewhere on your network ? Just reset the position of the `response` and process it as you want might be the answer to the question in its current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to provide a stream in the second parameter of `TIdHTTP.Get()`. If you want to save to file use a file stream:

```
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
....
Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
try
  HTTP.Get(..., Stream);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Or if you want in a memory stream like this:

```
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
....
Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  HTTP.Get(..., Stream);
  Stream.Position := 0; // seek to the beginning of the stream
  // do something with the stream
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: @TLama Maybe. Perhaps this answer will elicit the extra information. In which case I will gladly delete.

Comment: @TLama why u so aggressive :/

Comment: @TLama is not aggressive and he makes a very good point. The question is somewhat vague and I think TLama is right to question my answer. So I managed to make a good guess. Does that mean that the question was as clear as it could be? Nobody is trying to be aggressive, but we would just ask you to try and be a bit more clear when asking.

Comment: okay, i am sorry about this. So if you want, i can delete this Q

Comment: It's fine. There's no problem. We're all cool. Nothing more to do here.  :-)